# in windows 7, what is moving my windows automatically when i move my mouse on the edge of the screen?

Tags: windows-7, mouse, synaptics-touchpad

I have synaptics 15.0.24.0, windows 7, aero snap disabpled. both windows and driver came pre installed in this lenovo, bought on july 2011.

when i move a window partially out of the screen, and i move the mouse on the edge the window is, it automatically moves the window back to the screen.

i want to stop this.

this don't happen in safe mode, so is definitely some third party application

Comment: Sounds like a 3rd party (the notebook manufacturer perhaps) utility maybe?  Does it do this in safe mode?

Comment: it's a brand new lenovo. synaptics driver is lenovo customized as well. but i don't see any option for this anywhere.

Comment: Answer the question. Does it happen in Safe Mode?

Comment: No, it dont happen in safe mode. I'm sure it's some program doing this. probably the synaptics driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was something called "Lenovo Auto Scroll". Just uninstalled it from control panel add/remove programs.